# Compare field in the table and calculated field in django-orm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I calculated one variable using the annotate and now i want to compare it with the existing field. So how can I do that?

**models.py**

```
 class Book(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        price = models.IntegerField()
```

**query is look like this**

```
aggregate_query = {
     "max-price": (
          aggregate(Avg('price'))
     )
}
input_queryset = Books.objects.annotate(**aggregate_query)
```

So now i want to improve the query to filter the data of those books whose price is below the max and more than the average value.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some additional information, code samples, things you've tried, and a concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db.models import Max

max_price = Book.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price'))
```

You get the max price.

```
from django.db.models import Avg
average = Book.objects.all().aggregate(Avg('price'))
```

Now, you have the max price and average.

```
Book.objects.filter(price__lte = max_price,price__gte=average)
```

or

```
from django.db.models import Q
Book.objects.filter(Q(price__lte=max_price),Q(price__gte=average))
```

**[For reference use this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/)**

**Thank You !!!!**

Answer (score 1):

We do not have to check the maximum since, well, the maximum is the book with the largest value, so all items have a price which is less than or equal to the average.

You can fetch the average in a single query with:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

avg = Books.objects.aggregate(
    avg=Avg('price')
)['avg']
```

and then filter with:

```
Books.objects.filter(price__gte=avg)
```

If you determine the maximum based on a filter condition, we can fetch bot the maximum and average with the same query:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Max

aggs = Books.objects.filter(
    # …
).aggregate(
    avg=Avg('price'),
    max=Max('price')
)

Books.objects.filter(price__range=(aggs['avg'], aggs['max']))
```